# If we synchronise a block of code say setAttribute("var1",obj1) in Servlet then will other user be able to access that resource

Tags: java, servlets, concurrency, synchronization

If we synchronise a block of code say setAttribute("var1",obj1) in Servlet then will other user be able to access that resource. If they won't be able to access it then does it mean the other user needs to wait a considerable amount of time?

Answer (score 0):

Using synchronized should be unnecessary. For instance, Tomcat stores attributes in a threadsafe data structure (a ConcurrentHashMap). Obviously not every servlet container is open source allowing us to check on what it's doing, but we do know that  servlets are necessarily getting traversed concurrently by many threads and any kind of attribute updating you do needs to be done in a threadsafe way, so it makes sense that the servlet container should handle it.

If you did need to do this, just using synchronized on the setter would not be adequate, because that wouldn't in itself make the change visible to other threads reading that attribute. You would also need synchronize on the code reading that attribute. Again, as an application developer this isn't something in your control, as the implementation of how that attribute is stored and accessed is up to the app server.

For how you figure out what is safe and what isn't, there is a relevant passage in Java Concurrency in Practice, section 4.5.1: Interpreting  Vague Documentation:

> Since it is impossible to imagine a single-threaded context in which these objects would be useful, one has to assume that they have been made thread-safe, even though the specification does not explicitly require this. Besides, if they required client-side locking, on what lock should the client code synchronize? The documentation doesn't say, and it seems absurd to guess. This "reasonable assumption" is further bolstered by the examples in the specification and official tutorials that show how to access `ServletContext` or `HttpSession` and do not use any client-side synchronization.

This is assuming the question is about synchronizing on the ServletContext. The issue of the thread safety of the objects you put in the ServletContext is the application developer's responsibility, not the servlet container's. Putting synchronized on the setAttribute method doesn't help for that, either.